# how to set sope for cloudfoundry admin-ui

Tags: cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa

I installed cf-admin-ui: https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/admin-ui, and started, when I login with default user admin, it says:

Insufficient scope for user 
'admin'

what shoud I do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is add group `admin_ui.admin` to the scope of that user. You can do that by executing this command:

```
uaac member add admin_ui.admin <user>
```

Of course you need to have configured your uaac to use admin client token with scim.write scope. If not follow the following instructions:

```
# Target your UAA and get the 'admin' token
uaac target http://uaa.10.244.0.34.xip.io
uaac token client get admin -s admin-secret

# Add 'scim.write' if not already there and re-get token
uaac client update admin --authorities "`uaac client get admin | \
    awk '/:/{e=0}/authorities:/{e=1;if(e==1){$1="";print}}'` scim.write"
uaac token client get admin -s admin-secret
```

You should have also created the `admin_ui.admin group`. If not do this:

```
# Create a new group and add the 'admin' user to it
uaac group add admin_ui.admin
uaac member add admin_ui.admin admin

# Create the new UAA admin_ui_client
uaac client add admin_ui_client \
 --authorities cloud_controller.admin,cloud_controller.read,cloud_controller.write,openid,scim.read \
 --authorized_grant_types authorization_code,client_credentials,refresh_token \
 --autoapprove true \
 --scope admin_ui.admin,admin_ui.user,openid \
 -s admin_ui_secret
```

Comment: @Chris_vr You need to install UAAC CLI https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-uaac. Using this you can run the commands on your terminal.

Comment: I followed the steps mentioned above .still I am getting Scope Error

Insufficient scope for user .I tried with new user also "cf create-user user1 user123 uaac member add admin_ui.admin user1 ..this also not working .please help me